# Migration from Jxls to Jxls2 method invocation

Tags: jxls

We are migrating a project from Jxls 1.x to Jxls 2.2.8. In our current template we are using a Spring MessageSource to localize the titles of the report using messageSource.getMessage("message.key", locale). It works for the 1.x version but in the 2.x version it doesn't resolver the message.

[This is our current template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LY0C.jpg)

The message resolution fails when the method has parameters but when we call the toString() method in the messageSource object it works and prints the string in the cell.

The code in our class is:

```
public void convertToXLS(final Map<String, Object> p_model, final InputStream p_template, final OutputStream p_file, final Locale p_locale) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
    DeviceEventsDownloadWebModel deviceEventsDownloadWebModel = (DeviceEventsDownloadWebModel) p_model.get("deviceEventsDownloadWebModel");

Context context = new Context();
context.putVar("messageSource", getMessageSource());
context.putVar("locale", p_locale);
context.putVar("deviceEvents", deviceEventsDownloadWebModel.getDeviceEvents());

JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(p_template, p_file, context);
}
```

Any sugestion to solve the problem? We also try it setting the messageSource as a function but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! We have discovered the problem. The getMessage() method from the MessageSource class has the signature: String key, Object[] parameters, Locale locale and we were passing only 2 parameters.